# Is there a way i can make an imported CSS library affect only specific complements or elements in React JS

Tags: css, reactjs

In my React Application,i'm using React-Bootstrap and i've imported 
**https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css**

In order to style some other components, i imported MDBreact library, when i did so,the components (that were styled using bootstrap.min.css) have been effected by the exist of MDB library.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Theorically, just import what you need where you need it ? You usually import bootstrap in your main component, but if you want it only in a child, nothing prevent you from importing it here.

Comment: Thank you for your response ,actually i did that and i had the same issue.